# Why is jest.fn() not working after await?

Tags: node.js, async-await, jestjs

I use jest.fn()-functions for testing a node restapi server. I make extensive use of async/await and hit a problem I stripped down to this:

> test1.js

```
const test1 = async (res) => {
    res.status(500).send();  // Works here

    // Use a timer as an example, but should work with any promises
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 500));

    res.status(500).send();  // Doesn't work here
}

module.exports = test1;
```

> test1.test.js

```
const jest = jest;

import test1 from './test1';

const res01 = {};

let status;
let send;

beforeEach(() => {
    status = jest.fn();
    send = jest.fn();

    status.mockReturnValue({
        send
    });

    res01.status = status;
});

test('just testing ...', () => {
    test1(res01);
    expect(status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(500);
    expect(send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

> Jest-Settings

```
"jest": {
    "verbose": true,
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "globals": {
      "NODE_ENV": "test"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js"
    ],
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(less|css|jpg|png)$": "<rootDir>/src/test/empty-module.js"
    }
  },
```

If res.status(500).send() if placed before the first use of an await, the test succeeds, when it's placed after the test fails. status is not called. Why?

Comment: Maybe you need to `await` your call to `test1` ? https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await

Comment: That was it. Thx. Make an answer out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your test, you have to `await` your `async` method.

ref : https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await